# How to stop someone from calling URL on server

Tags: web-development, web, server-side, client-side, flask

I am very new to web development and am trying to create a website using client/server model. From what I understand, the front-end (client-side) calls URLs specified on the server to get information. So if my website was www.example.com, when the user clicks a button on my site, a request will be sent to www.example.com/api/buttonClicked, and my server will then run the logic and return a response correct?

But simply by using developer tools on Chrome, anyone can see the URL the request is being sent to (www.example.com/api/buttonClicked) and the data being sent. How can i prevent someone from calling this URL? Or even if they did call it, how can i prevent my server from giving them a response?

If it helps, I am using Flask to build the server

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot prevent someone from calling your URL directly.

What you *can* do, however, is reject invalid requests.

You can add a unique key to each response which is then returned in the next request. If a request has an invalid or missing key, ignore it.

This is the basic idea behind a [session](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_%28computer_science%29). In fact, you may be able to use sessions in your framework to do this (I am not familiar with Flask).

Comment: Thanks. So just to see if I understand, I can give each user a unique key (when they log in). When they send a request to the server, they must provide this unique key. If the key is invalid then I don't give a response. Is my understanding correct? Thanks again

Comment: @kev correct. You can either ignore the request entirely if you want, or redirect to another page such as the home page or an error page.